# Avoid injection for MySQL explain tool

Tags: mysql, security, explain

We are trying to develop a web tool to run EXPLAN command to our database. So even the developers do not have permission to run queries directly, they could use the tool to run EXPLAIN to investigate the performance of the query. Basically it is an editor and developers could type a query there, hit the button, and then in the backend the server runs EXPLAN to the query and returns the result.

Msql query optimizer perform differently on our production (and production snapshot) then our development/test databases. We can't always reproduce an issue with the query optimizer in our development database. And this is why we need the tool.

We have some security concerns on it. As the input is SQL, how could we make sure that there is no SQL injection? For example, if the input is something like "select * from users; drop users;", the server will run "Explain select * from users; drop users" which would delete the user table.

Comment: Why do developers not have permission to run queries on a database?

Comment: @Arjan Because the data are very sensitive and private customer info so only authorized people could access them.

Comment: In that case you should provide the developers with an anonymised version of the database, one is which the sensitive data is replaced with (more or less) random values. A DBA should be able to provide that. (And when it comes to performance, you need to work with tables that are at least comparable with the live data.)

Comment: This is all a matter of trust, and if you can't trust your developers to not run stupid or malicious queries you can't do this. SQL has a very complicated and nuanced syntax so it's not necessarily easy to write a validator that can 100% ensure there's nothing harmful in a given `EXPLAIN` statement. Remember, companies have database administrators for a reason, trusted individuals that can help your developers uncover performance problems. Letting your average developer loose on a production server is a super bad idea.

Comment: When a whole SQL query is intended to be run, it has nothing to do with SQL injection. It's a general security-related issue.